# Change backdrop to static for open bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Can I change backdrop to 'static' while my modal is open?

I have modal with form submit button. When I click this button I show loading spinner on my modal and that is the moment when I want to change backdrop to static

I tried `$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})`, but I can still close my modal by clicking the backdrop or using escape button.

Second step should be changing backdrop back to true, but I didn't try this yet, because first I need to set backdrop to static.

I could set backdrop to static on modal show, but I want to avoid this and change it after submit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your use-case, but why don't you initialize the modal with background: static and keyboard: false? Why do you need to change it while it's open?

Comment: Because all of my other modals could be closed with escape button or clicking outside the modal. I don't want to have only one modal that user can't close like others and I shouldn't change all other modals. This is special case. On submit I show spinner on modal and I want to disable closing modal while spinner is active.

Comment: This is a valid use case.  Open the modal and allow to be closed but once a certain action is started prevent the modal from closing until that action is complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I solved this. Maybe it is not the best solution, but it is working for my special case.

I added `$('#myModal').off('click');` just after I show loading spinner on submit. This prevents from closing modal with mouse click.

There was a problem with disabling `escape` button, because browsers stops page loading when user press this button. So I decided to hide the spinner to unlock the form with this code:

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    $('#myLoadingSpinner').hide();
  }
});
```

Edit:
I found another solution for backdrop:

```
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

I tried this also for `keyboard = false`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip man!
What I had for my case is - const bsDentalModal = new bootstrap.Modal(dentalModal);
Then I accessed the bsDentalModal._config.backdrop = true to make it dismissible again and bsDentalModal._config.keyboard = true for hitting Esc key.
Works like a charm, not sure how safe since I am accessing a private _ member but just enough to save a tight deadline.
Much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

I had a modal that could be opened 2 different ways.  When the user opened it one way, I wanted them to be able to close the modal.  When they opened it the other way I didn't want them to be able to close it.

I found this question and used the solution from the original poster.  I also tried adding keyboard which now works:

```
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.keyboard = false;
```

Comment: same here... I believe this is the bootstrap 4 _config. but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had a different JavaScript object returned and thus the following solution:

```
$myModal.data("bs.modal")._config.backdrop = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found, that in Bootstrap 5 this is slightly different:

```js
modal = new bootstrap.Modal($('.modal'));
modal._config.backdrop = 'static'; // or true
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method I've come up with is attaching to the `hide.bs.modal` event and calling `preventDefault()`.  This doesn't technically set the backdrop to static, but it achieves the same effect in a toggleable manner.

```js
let $myModal = $('#myModal');

function preventHide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

// if you have buttons that are allowed to close the modal
$myModal.find('[data-dismiss="modal"]').click(() => 
    $myModal.off('hide.bs.modal', preventHide));

function disableModalHide() {
    $myModal.on('hide.bs.modal', preventHide);
}

function enableModalHide() {
    $myModal.off('hide.bs.modal', preventHide);
}
```

(Disclaimer, I didn't test making buttons allowed to hide the modal, as that wasn't my scenario.  If it doesn't work, just call `.modal('hide')` from the `click()` callback.)

Comment: preventDefault on hide.bs.modal is the cleanest solution and works when the esc key is pressed too

Answer (score 1):

You can disallow closing of a modal when clicking outside of it, as well as on <kbd>esc</kbd> button. For example, if your modal ID is `signUp`:

```
jQuery('#signUp').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    jQuery(this).data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
    jQuery(this).data('bs.modal').options.keyboard = false;
});
```