# Change Bootstrap modal backdrop settings while open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to change the backdrop setting of my modal to 'static' as a response to an event, so that it becomes non-dismissable. I tried this by setting `$('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static',keyboard:false })` after clicking on a button inside the modal, with no luck.

The effect I want is similar to the effect from [nakupanda's bootstrap-dialog](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) (see *Manipulating Buttons* section, when `dialog.setClosable(true);` is triggered on click of the 'Click to disable and spin' button, the modal is no longer closable)

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4xdynyj/).

I know this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016616/change-bootstrap-modal-settings-dynamically) but it doesn't have a proper answer. I know this is possible somehow, but I fail to analyze nakupanda's code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change backdrop to static for open bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768034/change-backdrop-to-static-for-open-bootstrap-modal?noredirect=1#comment85277658_38768034)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try changing `modal`'s option as below:

```
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

Here's the **[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e4xdynyj/1/)**

Comment: this is the best answer.

Comment: This is the best solution for the problem. Kudos sir.

Comment: @JamesA Kudos and Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for ages on how to do this!

Comment: @JohnDoe.. Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 10):

For anyone attempting to do this on v4, you need to change:

```
$("#myModal").data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

to

```
$("#myModal").data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = 'static';
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just initialize the modal with options at page load instead of on button click?

just define a document ready fn and put the below code in it.

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  })
```

Comment: Yes I could do this, but this defeats the purpose of the question. The modal should still be closable until the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this: http://codepen.io/bwobst/pen/GrKBKy?editors=1010

```
$('#open-modal').click(function(evt) {
  $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static'});
  $('.modal button').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

When you click the 'open modal' button it sets the backdrop to static and disables the buttons within the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution.  The issue is that even if you set the backdrop to static, there is still a click listener.

My solution is here.  https://jsfiddle.net/25zbf094/2/

JavaScript

```
$('#makeIndismissable').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').prop('onclick',null).off('click');
});

$('#close').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal("hide")
})
```

I kept the HTML mostly unchanged, but added the id of "close" to the close button.  And as you can see above, you can still close the modal by pressing the X in the top right.